# I need to know how to get my function to return floats. I'm confused as to where I put the float tag

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

I am currently working through a python tutorial that has asked me to create a random function and run it 10 different ways. I'm stuck on how to actually get it to use floats. I Assume I should post the entire thing and just point out where I'm trying to get float to work

```
def volume (length, width, height):
    print "the object is %d cm long, %d cm wide, and %d cm high" % (length, width, height),
    total_volume = float(length * width * height)
    print "The total volumeis %d cm3" % total_volume


print "Direct input:"
volume (10, 20, 30)

print "direct input variables:"
length = (10)
width = (20)
height = (30)
volume (length, width, height)

print "direct input variables and math"
volume (length + 10, width +20, height +30)

print "direct input math"
volume (10 + 10, 20 +20, 30 + 30)


print "user input with int(raw_input)"
length2 = int(raw_input("what is the length? "))
width2 = int(raw_input("what is the width? "))
height2 = int(raw_input("what is the height? "))
volume (length2, width2, height2)

#here is the first problem
print "user input with float(raw_input)"
length3 = float(raw_input("what is the length? "))
width3 = float (raw_input("what is the width? "))
height3 = float (raw_input("what is the height? "))
volume (length3, width3, height3)

#Doesn't work here either`
print "float(raw_input) + variables"
print "the base oject size is 10 * 10 * 10"
print "why is this important? IT ISN'T!!!!!"
print "However, eventually I will make one that calculates the increase in volume"
length4 = length + float(raw_input("How much length are you adding? "))
width4 = width + float(raw_input("How much width are you adding? "))
height4 = height + float(raw_input("How much height are you adding? "))
volume (length4, width4, height4)
```

These two parts simply refuse to return a float. Here is what I tried so far.

I've attempted to add float when calling on the function variable, as follows

volume float(length4, width4, height4)

I tried to add float to the actual definition part of the function as follows

def volume float(length, width, height):

as you can see, I have float placed in the actually math part of the function, with no effect.

It must be possible to make this work. I am hoping someone more knowledgeable can point the way, and I am out of ideas

Comment: Use the `return` statement with whatever value (variable) you want to return: `return total_volume`.

Comment: For the record: Python is not a C or similar language: there is no need to declare types (but you can [hint at types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) since Python 3.5).

Comment: Not that you are also being inconsequent: you cast `total_volume` to a float in your function, then print it using a `%d` (integer) specifier.

Comment: I wish I knew what you meant by declaring types. Python is the first language I've used. Not very far into learning it.

Comment: "Declaring types" in this context means you tell the interpreter/compiler/whatever what type your variable is, or what type of variable your function returns. Python deduces this from the context, and is flexible in that: you can set `a = 1` and `a` is an `int`, then in the next line you set `a = '1'` and a`a is a `str`. For some other languages, you explicitly need to tell it that `a` is an `int` (the declaration): that language will not deduce it from the assignment `a = 1`. Nor can you afterwards change the type: once an `int`, always an `int`. As said, this is not the case in Python.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your math, you're just printing the result as an integer by using `%d`. If you use `%f` instead, you should see the correct result:

```
print "The total volume is %f cm3" % total_volume
# Here ---------------------^
```

Comment: Thank you. Probably wouldn't have thought have that. Need to pay more attention to formatters I guess

Answer (score 1):

Use `%f` instead of `%d` when you want float instead of integer.

Also, you can format your strings more with `"%0.2f"` where 2 is how many decimal places you would like.

```
>>> x = 1.2342345
>>> print "%0.2f" % x
1.23
```